# pass pointer to template member of template class

Tags: c++, oop

I'm searching for a way to have a function of my template class which accepts as a parameter a member of the template (it could be either one of its arguments or functions).

model.h

```
template <class T>
class Model
{
public:
    Model(){}
    void relate(int T::*, int ){}
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "model.h"

class element
{
public:
    element();

    char getA(){return this->a;}
    int getB(){return this->b;}

    char a;
    int b;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Model<element *> model;
    return 0;
}
```

it gives the `creating pointer to member of non-class type ‘element*’` error.
I agree with that since pointer must point to some defined type memory area.

My final goal is to tell my class that I want to relate a specific member of its template with some number which later will be used to order different members in a list which later will be displayed.
This wont be used with types such as `Model<int>` but only with other classes.

Comment: *it gives the creating pointer to member of non-class type ‘element*’* No it does not. Show a [mcve]. We can't guess what you're trying to do. There's nothing wrong with the code you've shown.

Comment: Compile fine [here](https://godbolt.org/z/rh8sd7)... which is your problem?

Comment: note that `int T::*p` is not a pointer to a member of the template, but a pointer to member of `T`. I suppose you are just confusing "template" with "template parameter". `T` is not the template

Comment: sorry it was too "minimal"... let me rework the code...

Comment: in your example `T = element *` but you probably want `T = element`

Answer (score 1):

Your instantiate a `Model<element*>` hence this:

```
void relate(int T::*, int ){}
```

is (just hypotheically):

```
void relate(int element*::*, int) {}
```

Its a "pointer to member of a pointer type". If you instantiate a `Model<element>` your code works fine. Alternatively you can use `std::remove_pointer<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
suddenly I'm figuring out... I used a poiter as a template...

but the game changes now...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Model<element> model;
    element e;
    model.relate(&element::getA(), 0);   // <- call to non static-member error
    model.relate(&element::getB(), 0);   // <- call to non static-member error
    model.relate(&element::a, 0);    // <- type mismatch error
    model.relate(&element::b, 0);    // <- no error
}
```